# d3 graph has client's time zone instead of data's

Tags: javascript, graph, client, d3.js

I'm using D3 to graph some data, and if I change my time zone away from my current one, the time scale changes based on my client's time zone. I would rather be able to force the graph to display in one time zone because that's what the data makes sense when being looked at.

I am using

```
x.domain([lowerTime, upperTime])
```

to create the x axis, but I'm not sure how I'd take advantage of

```
x.timeFormat()
```

to force this domain to be in a certain time zone, can anyone  help here?

Comment: What format are the dates in your data in?

Answer (score 2):

By using [Time Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) you can get the following:

> # d3.time.scale.utc()
>
> Constructs a new time scale with the default domain and range; the ticks and tick format are configured for UTC time.

So, in the end you can do:

```
scale = d3.time.scale.utc()
scale.domain([lowerTime, upperTime])
```

Now you have the same time on any client. You still have to figure out what is your current time in UTC, but it is way easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UTC, or [format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md) the [tick labels](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9764126) to use a specific timezone